# Where is /usr/share/applications/defaults.list on Arch?

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, mime-types, plasma5

Where is /usr/share/applications/defaults.list on Arch?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103658/discussion-on-question-by-mountainx-for-monica-okular-is-being-used-to-handle-ss).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where is /usr/share/applications/defaults.list on Arch?

There is no `defaults.list` in Arch. `defaults.list` is a legacy file which is not recommended any more and Arch is a rolling-release which only keeps the latest and greatest. It's replaced by `*mimeapps.list` and this could be verified from

https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/latest/ar01s02.html

To verify it more, this [man](https://helpmanual.io/man3/File::MimeInfo::Applications-pm/) page mentions explicitly,

```
It will also attempt a last-resort fallback to the legacy file    
$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/defaults.list
```