# What is the procedure to update mime type associations in KDE?

Tags: kde, mime-types, plasma5, xdg

I would like to revert to the default mime definitions at the system level, and also rebuild my local mime database. I am running Arch Linux KDE.

The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications) says,

> If you use a [desktop environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_environment) you should first check if it provides its own utility. That should be preferred over these alternatives.

**Does KDE provide such a utility** or should I use the generic [xdg-utils](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-utils)?

The Arch Wiki [mentions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications#mimeapps.list) several mimeapps.list files, but I have never had those. Does KDE not use them?

The only mimeapps.list file I have had is `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

**What is the procedure to put KDE's house in order in regard to mime types (for local user and system-wide)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does KDE provide such a utility or should I use the generic xdg-utils?

Yes, **KDE** read these **mimeapps.list**. The code is written in [mimetypedata.cpp](https://cgit.kde.org/kde-cli-tools.git/tree/keditfiletype/mimetypedata.cpp)

```
KSharedConfig::Ptr profile = KSharedConfig::openConfig("mimeapps.list", KConfig::NoGlobals, QStandardPaths::GenericConfigLocation);
```

**KDE** would try to read them in this order

```
.config/kde-mimeapps.list
.config/mimeapps.list
/etc/xdg/kde-mimeapps.list
/etc/xdg/mimeapps.list
/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Not having some of these files is not a problem because it depends on your KDE version and your distribution. KDE would consult whichever is found.

> What is the procedure to put KDE's house in order in regard to mime types (for local user and system-wide)?

For local users, you can edit or create the files in your `.config` directory. Whereas, for system-wide use, you can create the ones in `/etc` instead.

However, most of the time there is no need to touch those files manually. You already have `~/.config/mimeapps.list` created. If you want to change the application associated with any file extension just `right-click -> Open With -> Other Application...`. Choose your new application and tick the checkbox **Remember application association for all files of type...**. This would edit your `~/config/mimeapps.list` for you. E.g, if you want to change **PDF** association to **evince** instead of **okular**, you do this and the entry

```
application/pdf=org.gnome.Evince.desktop;
```

would be added to your `mimeapps.list`. The `application/pdf` is guessed from `/usr/share/mime/application/pdf.xml` entry. So, feel free to learn the syntax this way or use `xdg-mime` instead. Here is the [MIME applications associations specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/latest/)

Comment: What tool or procedure is used to create these mimeapps.list files for KDE? Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: @MountainX-for-Monica: I edited my previous answer so it also covers this new question.

Comment: Do you have any insight into my related question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/563102/15010 I'm still looking for an answer there. Thank you.

Comment: @MountainX-for-Monica: Sure, I will try to help you there.